# Whats is this error? error: array type 'char [400]' is not assignable

Tags: c

I'm coding and my IDE is showing this error. Whats is it?

```
error: array type 'char [400]' is not assignable name[400] = get_string("Your name: ");
```

The code:

```
char name[400] = "";

do
{
    name = get_string("Your name: ");
}
while(name <= 0);
```

Thank You.

Comment: Read `C` book on types and pointers. It is mentioned there.

Comment: See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Use a good compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Take inspiration from existing open source programs in C like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: Are you following the CS50 course?

Comment: So if name is a string, what do you mean by checking `name <= 0`?

Comment: CS50 is the root of all problems here, because it has the student thinking there is a string class in C and that we can assign to it like any other variable. And so this question makes perfect sense, because that's how they were taught... We should gather a bunch of SO veterans and write an open letter to Harvard, demanding that they fix their harmful class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays cannot be assigned to. The expectation that they should be comes from two places:

- we can use the `=` symbol for initialization, which so happens to coincide with the symbol `=` for assignment. And we know we can initialize arrays with `=`, so we automatically assume we should be able to assign as well.

  ```
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}; //OK, initialization
  arr = {4, 5, 6}; //Error, assignment
  ```
- most of the types we deal with are assignable

Well, arrays are not. There are other ways to write to arrays circumventing direct assignment. For your particular case, you are probably looking for `strcpy` function.